# Absolute depth from iPhone X back camera using disparity from AVDepthData?

Tags: ios, swift, depth, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm trying to estimate the absolute depth (in meters) from an `AVDepthData` object based on this equation: ***depth = baseline x focal_length / (disparity + d_offset)***.  I have all the parameters from `cameraCalibrationData`, but does this still apply to an image taken in Portrait mode with iPhone X since the two cameras are offset vertically?  Also based on [WWDC 2017 Session 507](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/), the disparity map is *relative*, but the [`AVDepthData` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata) states that the disparity values are in 1/m.  So can I apply the equation on the values in the depth data as is or do I need to do some additional processing beforehand?

```
var depthData: AVDepthData

do {
  depthData = try AVDepthData(fromDictionaryRepresentation: auxDataInfo)

} catch {
  return nil
}

// Working with disparity
if depthData.depthDataType != kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32 {
  depthData = depthData.converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32)
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(depthData.depthDataMap, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

// Scale Intrinsic matrix to be in depth image pixel space
guard var intrinsicMatrix = depthData.cameraCalibrationData?.intrinsicMatrix else{ return nil}

let referenceDimensions = depthData.cameraCalibrationData?.intrinsicMatrixReferenceDimensions

let depthWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthData.depthDataMap)
let depthHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthData.depthDataMap)

let depthSize = CGSize(width: depthWidth, height: depthHeight)

let ratio: Float =  Float(referenceDimensions.width) / Float(depthWidth)

intrinsicMatrix[0][0] /= ratio;
intrinsicMatrix[1][1] /= ratio;
intrinsicMatrix[2][0] /= ratio;
intrinsicMatrix[2][1] /= ratio;

// For converting disparity to depth    
let baseline: Float = 1.45/100.0 // measured baseline in m

// Prepare for lens distortion correction
let lut = depthData.cameraCalibrationData?.lensDistortionLookupTable

let center = depthData.cameraCalibrationData?.lensDistortionCenter
let centerX: CGFloat = center!.x / CGFloat(ratio)
let centerY: CGFloat = center!.y / CGFloat(ratio)
let correctedCenter = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY);            

// Build point cloud
var pointCloud = Array<Any>()

for dataY in 0 ..< depthHeight{
  let rowData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthData.depthDataMap)! + dataY * CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(depthData.depthDataMap)
  let data = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: rowData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self), count: depthWidth)

  for dataX in 0 ..< depthWidth{
    let dispZ = data[dataX] 
    let pointZ = baseline * intrinsicMatrix[0][0] / dispZ 

    let currPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: dataX,y: dataY)
    let correctedPoint: CGPoint = lensDistortionPoint(for: currPoint, lookupTable: lut!, distortionOpticalCenter: correctedCenter,imageSize: depthSize)

    let pointX = (Float(correctedPoint.x) - intrinsicMatrix[2][0]) * pointZ / intrinsicMatrix[0][0];
    let pointY = (Float(correctedPoint.y) - intrinsicMatrix[2][1]) * pointZ / intrinsicMatrix[1][1];

    pointCloud.append([pointX,pointY,pointZ])
  }
}

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(depthData.depthDataMap, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
```

Comment: How did you get the baseline value? Did you measure it yourself?

Comment: From my experience the final point cloud from disparity data looks correct if you just invert it `depth = 1/disparity`.
No need for baseline calculation.